# How to Make star Rating using django Database

Tags: django

I have a rating for products stored in django models, now I want the rating to show as a star

```
  <script>
    alert('hello')
    const Select = (size) => {
    const children = form.children
    console.log(children[0])
    for (let i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if(i <= size) {
            children[i].classList.add('checked')
        } else {
            children[i].classList.remove('checked')
        }
    }
  }


  Select(ratings);
</script>
```

this is the handler for js

```
          <form>
              <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-1x my-btn " id="first"></button>
              <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-1x my-btn" id="second"></button>
              <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-1x my-btn" id="third"></button>
              <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-1x my-btn" id="fourth"></button>
              <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-1x my-btn" id="fifth"></button>
          </form>
```

this is the form, Now i dont know if i have to trigger to make the js work or what esle solution do i have

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in https://github.com/wildfish/django-star-ratings - it looks like this may do what you need. If so you can either drop it in to replace your code, or read through the code to see how it works.